# Django REST framework - prevent data access for user view?

Tags: ember.js, django-rest-framework

In my api, I have a /users endpoint which currently shows (eg address) details of all users currently registered. This needs to be accessed by the (Ember) application (eg to view a user shipping address) but for obvious reasons I can't allow anyone to be able to view the data (whether that be via the browsable api or as plain JSON if we restrict a view to just use the JSONRenderer). I don't think I can use authentication and permissions, since the application needs to log a user in from the front end app (I am using token based authentication) in the first instance. If I use authentication on the user view in Django for instance, I am unable to login from Ember.

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**

Hi, I wanted to come back on this.

For authentication on the Ember side I'm using Ember Simple Auth and token based authentication in Django. All is working fine - I can log into the Ember app, and have access to the token.

What I need to be able to do is to access the user; for this I followed the code sample here https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/guides/managing-current-user.md

I have tested the token based authentication in Postman, using the token for my logged in user - and can access the /users endpoint. (This is returning all users - what I want is for only the user for whom I have the token to be returned but that's for later!).

The question is how to do I pass the (token) header in any Ember requests, eg

```
this.store.findAll('user') .... etc
```

This is clearly not happening currently, and I'm not sure how to fix this.

**UPDATE**

Fixed it. Turns out that the authorize function in my application adapter was not setting the headers, so have changed the code to set the headers explicitly:

```
authorize(xhr) {
    let { access_token } = this.get('session.data.authenticated');
    if (isPresent(access_token)) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Token ${access_token}`);
    }
},
headers: computed('session.data.authenticated.token', function () {
    const headers = {};
    if (this.session.isAuthenticated) {
        headers['Authorization'] = `Token ${this.session.data.authenticated.token}`
    }
    return headers;
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember is framework for creating SPAs. These run in the browser. So for Ember to get the data, you have to send the data to the browser.

The browser is **completely** under the control of the user. The browser is software that works for them, not for the owner of the website.

Any data you send to the browser, the user can access. Full stop.

---

If you want to limit which bits of the data the user can read from the API, then you need to write the logic to apply those limits *server-side* and not depend on the client-side Ember code to filter out the bits you don't want the user to see.

---

> I don't think I can use authentication and permissions, since the application needs to log a user in from the front end app (I am using token based authentication) in the first instance. If I use authentication on the user view in Django for instance, I am unable to login from Ember.

This doesn't really make sense.

Generally, this should happen:

1. The user enters some credentials into the Ember app
2. The ember app sends them to an authentication endpoint on the server
3. The server returns a token
4. The ember app stores the token
5. The ember app sends the token when it makes the request for data from the API
6. The server uses the token to determine which data to send back from the API

Comment: many thanks for getting back. I'm not saying the issue is connected with Ember. I have the authentication side of it down. The issue is at the API end, the (eg) /users endpoint making potentially sensitive (certainly private) info available to anyone who views that endpoint. I cannot restrict this endpoint because the inital login would not work obviously. What I considering is just returning the user ID from the api and then making the necessary ajax calls in Ember once I've logged in, to obtain the private info I need

Comment: sorry just to clarify, there is no issue with authentication, that is fine. The problem I was having was that when I was logged in, I was obtaining the user via eg /users/1 in Ember. The concern is that if the endpoint /users returns sensitive info, that will available for anyone to view - as stated in my previous comment, I'm going to obtain that after logging in ... not sure if this is the best way to achieve this but certainly better than letting anyone view all user information!

Comment: " I cannot restrict this endpoint because the inital login would not work obviously." — Then your initial login is broken and you need to reimplement it as I described in this answer.

Comment: Sorry - I hoped I cleared that up, there is no problem with authentication and hence the initial login. The issue with authenticating at the Django end is that I can't then grab the user information (eg shipping addresses) that I might need. I'm now just going to return the user ID from Django (which will remain exposed) but then use some calls back to Django after the user is authenticated. It will work!